# Сохранение состояния LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

Я добавляю динамически в коде разные `View` элементы в прописанный в `layout.xml` `LinearLayout`.

При повороте экрана динамические вьюхи убиваются оставляя мой `LinearLayout` пустым.
Можно ли как-то загрузить последнее состояние `LinearLayout` перед поворотом?

Comment: Используйте  `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize` в `manifest` и при повороте ничего не потеряется

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**В Manifest'e:**

```
<activity
    android:name="...."
    android:theme="...."
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
```